# Fabricjs custom serialization

Tags: fabricjs

I would like to create a canvas in which I would load images of some entity. the images of these entities could change from time to time.
FabricJs provides a built in serialization & de-serialization mechanism using following methods
`fabric.Canvas#toJSON` to serialize the canvas and 
`fabric.Canvas#loadFromJSON` to de-serialize it but the problem with them is they serialize the image source as well which is enormous and useless in my case
(`fabric.Canvas#toDatalessJSON` & `fabric.Canvas#loadFromDatalessJSON` seems to work only for complex object but not images [gitHub Ref](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/370))

whats is the approach to this?
should customize serialization by serializing all the required properties and recreate objects based on those info?
I have even try to create a subclass of Image removing src from toObject to avoid serializing it but it seems that does not work as well

here is what I have tried with subclass

```
  fabric.MyImage = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Image, {
    type: 'MyImage',
    initialize: function(options) {
      options || (options = { })
      this.callSuper('initialize', options)
      this.set('artIndexes', options.artIndexes || '')
    },
    toObject: function() {
      const TO = this.callSuper('toObject')
      fabric.util.object.extend(TO, {
        artIndexes: this.get('artIndexes')
      })
      delete TO.src
      return TO
    },
    _render: function(ctx) {
      this.callSuper('_render', ctx)
    }// ,
    // fromURL: function(a, b) {
    //   this.callSuper('fromURL', a, b)
    // }
  })
  fabric.MyImage.fromObject = function (object, callback) {
    fabric.util.enlivenObjects(object.objects, function (enlivenedObjects) {
      delete object.objects
      callback && callback(new fabric.MyImage(enlivenedObjects, object))
    })
  }
  fabric.MyImage.async = true
```

and to add Image i would do somthing like this

```
let img = new fabric.MyImage({entetyReference: entetyRef})
img.setSrc(`${imageSource}`, image => {
  this.canvas.add(img)
})
```

but during serialization and de-serializatiin using FabricJs provided method the object get lost from canvas

**I am using latest version of fabricJs**

Comment: why the image source is enormous in your case? you should get your original url and not something bigger.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi: because I am storing the images as array buffer in file system and loading it from them, and basically the idea is not to serialize image source since it could change at anytime

Comment: I do not get your point. Your fromObject is wrong, looks for a group more than for an image. If you write a custom class and the image source depends from some other parameters, you have to output them in the object form, and make initialization retrieve the image from the parameters. In that  case you can skip source/src

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi: well fromObject was copied from some answer in stack overflow, there is no in dept documentation of creating custom classes, What I want to achieve creating myImage object which inherits fabric.Image and it's toObject method should not have src (to avoid serializing it) insted should have artIndexes using which I can refetch the imageSource manually and attach it to myImage object while de-serializing

Comment: I think Ill end up creating my own custom logic for serialization and de-serialization, but it would be nice to know if it is possible what I can to achieve (serializing a custom object inherited form fabric.Image without image source and attaching image source to them while de-serializing)

Comment: this is possible and the normal thing to do.